# Error when running rails server for the first time in a new dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am trying to run

```
rails server
```

for the first time in a new dev environment (OS X) and I am getting the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe4fe066c70> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/me/Me/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Do you have `actionmailer` gem installed?  Please share your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks, I just added my Gemfile, which I took directly from Michael Hartl's tutorial.

Comment: @vinodadhikary, the Gemfiles there now, thanks

Comment: try putting `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle update`

Comment: @vinodadhikary, DUDE, thanks! It was such an obvious error once you pointed it out, but I'm good now. Huge sigh of relief. The only thing is that instead of "rails, '4.0.0'", it's "gem 'rails', '4.0.0'" (ignoring the ""). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

comment the following line in application.rb

```
# require 'active_resource/railtie'
```

Its no longer required in Rails 4.

Still you can use it, using gem